# iText: Change page dimensions based on ResultSet

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I have a dynamic PDF that is being generated through iText1.4.6 (yes, I am stuck with this old version).  I am having trouble with two things:
1) Adding a watermark to all pages, not just the first.
2)  Changing the page Dimensions based on the amount of results in the resultSet.

Here is some code:

```
Document testScoreReport = new Document(PageSize.A4,50,50,25,230);
OutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();
PdfWriter writer = null;

writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(testScoreReport, outStream);    
testScoreReport.open(); 

Image watermark = Image.getInstance(CreateTestReport.class.getResource("/resource/img.jpg"));

// Build table
PdfPTable testTable = new PdfPTable(3);
PdfPCell cell1  = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Test Date", FONT)));
PdfPCell cell2  = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Test Name", FONT)));
PdfPCell cell3  = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Test Score", FONT)));
testTable.addCell(cell1);
testTable.addCell(cell2);
testTable.addCell(cell3);

// QUERY HERE
while (resultSet.next()) {

   if (resultTestCount > 20) {
      // NEW PAGE, SO PRINT WATERMARK AND CHANGE PAGE DIMENSIONS OF NEW PAGE
      resultTestCount = 0;
   }

   PdfPCell cell1  = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(testDate, FONT)));
   PdfPCell cell2  = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(testName, FONT)));
   PdfPCell cell3  = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(testScore, FONT)));

   resultTestCount++;
}

testScoreReport.close();
```

I think that is all of the relevant code.  I have tried to add the watermark to a table cell, or just add it in the while loop, but it just seems to ignore it.  The page dimensions - I have tried a few things, and nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

For Watermark examples, look for the keyword [Watermark](http://itextpdf.com/themes/keyword.php?id=226) on the official iText site. You'll discover that watermarks should be added using [page events](http://itextpdf.com/themes/keyword.php?id=204).

As for changing the page size, that's probably not a good idea (I don't have any clue as to why you'd want to do that in your case), but it can be done using [`Document.setPageSize()`](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/Document.html#setPageSize%28com.itextpdf.text.Rectangle%29). Note that the size of the page will only be different after the next [newPage()](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/Document.html#newPage%28%29) has been triggered.

Your code is somewhat confusing: you create a `PdfPTable`, but you're not adding it to the document. You create `PdfPCell` objects, but you're not adding them to the table. You say you want to change the page size based on the result set but you're not measuring the height of the rows (how will you define the dimension of the page?) and so on...

I'd like to know why you're stuck with that obsolete version and why your design is different from 'standard use' of iText.

Comment: The main reason for leaving out the things that you mentioned is because I didn't think it was relevant.  The height of the table rows are set in my code, as well as, adding the cells to the tables (and table to the document).  I have a footer image that will be at the bottom of my document, so when I hit the last page I need to change the dimensions of the page (not the actual page size)

Comment: OK, so now you know that you can change the size of the next page, but not of the current page. I hope this helps.

Comment: setPageSize() changes the page size, not the dimensions correct? Is there a way to change the dimensions? Similar to how it is done originally Document testScoreReport = new Document(PageSize.A4,50,50,25,230);

Comment: What is the difference between page size and dimensions? Are you referring to the margins which are set using setMargins()?